# How do I get an ng-model parameter back in a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to bind the ng-model parameter which was initially set in a controller  back to the controller 
I have something like this

```
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">

     First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
     Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
      </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = "Leo";
        $scope.lastName = "Messi";

        });
    </script>
```

I am trying to implement a PUT method in my controller, so I needed to bind the new  value back to the controller . I tried

```
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">
        <form>
         First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
         Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
         <button ng-click="UpdateProfile()"> Update </button>
         </form>
         </div>
```

then in  I updated my controller to

```
       <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = "Leo";
        $scope.lastName = "Messi";
        $scope.UpdateProfile = function()
           {
               $scope.newFirstName = firstName
           }
        });
    </script>
```

But I got an error saying firstName is not define.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: @N.V.Prasad, Will `this` refer to `that` ?

Comment: @kplus, all scope variables are two way data binding. So, you can simply get the latest value of `firstName` from `$scope.firstName` itself.

Comment: It didnt work, it gave the initial first name,instead of the new one

Comment: `$scope.newFirstName = $scope.firstName`. [Check this working PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/lOmic9Aw16bJqJGyQr9t?p=preview)

Comment: Why you are not using `$scope.firstName` like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/g1mxL8qt/)

Comment: @Abhilash P A- Pullelil, How will I get it in theUpdateProfile function, it seems to be returning the initial firtname but not the new one

Comment: @kplus, It supposed to get latest value in the `$scope.firtName`. But, if you are experiencing issue with this, there are some work around for this. Rename `$scope.firstName` to `$scope.myModel = {}; $scope.myModel.firstName = 'Leo'`, then try to get this on your controller

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
$scope.UpdateProfile = function()
    {
        $scope.newFirstName = $scope.firstName;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can make some changes to get your own version functioning..
**In controller:**

```
$scope.UpdateProfile = function(firstName)
{
    $scope.newFirstName = firstName
}
```

**In HTML:**

```
<button ng-click="UpdateProfile(firstName)"> Update </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already Pre-defined Scopes by filling Some values .Scope recognizes the Updated values it self .

Update your Code just like the Following :-

```
 $scope.newFirstName = $scope.firstName;
 $scope.newLastName = $scope.lastName;
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/NsoxahPcGUBtTYTlruBJ?p=preview

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope - can give you more information for better Understanding !!

Answer (score 0):

Your Code - you have attached firstName to the $scope variable which is an object internally and and firstName is its property.

For example if I create a sample testApp module with testController and attach a property test1 to it and console log the $scope variable.
then i can see whole $scope object in console.
// Code goes here

```
var app =angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testController',testController);
testController.$inject=['$scope'];

function testController($scope){
  $scope.test1="plunkr";
  console.log($scope);
}
```

[image: $scope object containing test1 property]

so you should access firstName as a property of $scope object not as a variable firstName
so your code should be

```
 $scope.firstName = "Leo";
    $scope.UpdateProfile = function()
               {
                   $scope.newFirstName = $scope.firstName
               }
       });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/zJ3X3XP9N1C0oZlvZ7mh?p=preview